# Hack Realm share database

Tags: mobile, realm, realm-object-server

I was wondering, if I create a share user entity on a Realm object server. If a user access to the database from his mobile. Could he see all the user data? I'm worry about sensible information on a shared database.

Comment: Especially the login/password in shared user database.

Comment: I have a user table where I store all users, this table is shared between all users. For instance if a user want to login, I check the credentials from this table. I was wondering if all the users password will be on all devices.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by a shared database? All Realms are associated with a user, so yes, anybody with access to that users login information could see the data.

However, normally you would architect the app in such a way that shared data are kept in a shared Realm with the shared ID shipping with the app and then have a login that would generate a true user specific Realm.

Note in this context, it is very important to keep in mind there is a difference between an app user and a Realm Mobile Platform user. It is not uncommon for an app user to know about multiple Realm Mobile Platform user IDs.

Comment: Ok, I'm talking about the app user. Every user has his own database on the Realm Object Server however I need a common database with all users to do the authentication. This table is a global at all users. That's mean the users tables will be store on local mobile ?

Comment: Are you making your own custom login solution? Because if you use the login from Realm you shouldn't be sharing any sensitive information.

Comment: Is it possible to set up multiple Realms so that one Realm is user-specific and another is shared between multiple users? Maybe share a Realm between only specific users (like some "group")?

Comment: Yes I'm making my own custom login solution. I didn't know that Realm has its own API for mobile users authentication. If you have a link, feel free to post it. Do you know what happen when you share a huge table between users ? It's hard to find a tutorial or a documentation on architecture.